# how can you add a classList to an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to automate my Battleship project so that the AI can play as well. I've tried doing this by taking a random position on the array and changing its classname to red one which is the shot's color. I've tried doing this `boxes[Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)][Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)].classList = "red"` but the classname doesn't change. Is there a way to change the class for a specific position in the array?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Ship from "../components/ShipGenerate.js";
import "../style/style.css";

function Grid(props) {
  let grid = new Array(10);
  let box = [];

  const [turn, setTurn] = useState(true)

  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i += 1) grid[i] = new Array(10).fill(0);

  const rnd = (r) => Math.trunc(Math.random() * r);

  for (let l = 0; l < 40; l += 1) {
    grid[rnd(10)][rnd(10)] = 1;
  }

  const boxes = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
    boxes.push(grid[i]);
  }

  const myShips = document.querySelectorAll(".ship");
// Here I try to apply the logic for chaing the classname
if (boxes === 0) {
boxes[Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)][Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)].classList = "red"
}

const handleClick = (e, ship) => {
        if (ship === 0) {
          e.target.classList.add("red");
        } else if (ship === 1) {
          e.target.classList.add("green");
        } else {
          return;
        }
      };


  return (
    <div className="game-wrapper">
      {myShips && (
        <div className="game-area">
          {boxes.map((item) => {
            return item.map((box) => {
              return (
                <div
                  onClick={(e) => handleClick(e, box)}
                  className={box === 1 ? "green" : "ship"}
                >
                </div>
              );
            });
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Grid;
```

Answer (score 1):

`.classList = "red"` will not work. `classList` is a read-only property. You must use its methods (like `add`, `remove`, `toggle`, `change`) to make changes.

So do:

```
boxes[Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)]
     [Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)].classList.add("red")
```

Depending on your actual case, you may want to use one of the other methods, depending on whether that box should keep its other color(s), or not.

Alternatively, you can *assign* the class name, thereby **removing any other class** that element has:

```
boxes[Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)]
     [Math.floor(Math.random()*boxes.length)].className = "red"
```

Answer (score 1):

in react, you should not handle dom directly. you can use `useState` hook to change data status.

in this code, I have used typescript, you can del ts type.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import './grid.scss';

function Grid(props: any) {
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState<number[][]>([]);
  const rnd = (r: number) => Math.trunc(Math.random() * r);

  useEffect(() => {
    let grid = new Array(10);
    for (let i = 0; i < grid.length; i += 1) grid[i] = new Array(10).fill(0);

    for (let l = 0; l < 40; l += 1) {
      grid[rnd(10)][rnd(10)] = 1;
    }
    setBoxes(grid);
  }, []);

  const handleClick = (row: number, col: number, ship: number) => {
    const newArr = boxes.concat(); // cant change state directly
    newArr[row][col] = 1 - ship; // 1->0, 0->1
    setBoxes(newArr);
  };

  return (
    <div className="game-wrapper">
      <div className="game-area">
        {boxes.map((item, row) => {
          return item.map((box, col) => {
            return <div onClick={() => handleClick(row, col, box)} className={box === 1 ? "green" : "ship"}></div>;
          });
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Grid;
```